# jQuery validation: different colors for different messages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Currently I am able to return different messages for different jQuery validation failures. The working code for that is shown below. In addition, I would like these messages to be different colors, i.e. red for the "Error" message and orange for the "Warning" message. How can I do this?

Here is the working code to display different messages for different errors—I also want these messages to be in different colors:

CSS

```
.error {
    color:red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#inputForm").validate(
          {
              rules:
              {
                  appleQty:{min:0, max:100, range: [4, 8]},
                  bananaQty:{min:0, max:100, range: [2, 4]},
                  cherryQty:{min:0, max:100, range: [80, 85]}
              }
          });
    });
    jQuery.validator.messages.min = 'Error: Minimum value is {0}.';
    jQuery.validator.messages.max = 'Error: Maximum value is {0}.';
    jQuery.validator.messages.range = 'Warning: Expected range is {0} to {1}.';
</script>
```

HTML

```
...
<tr><td>Apples</td><td> <input type="text" id="appleQty" name="appleQty" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Bananas</td><td> <input type="text" id="bananaQty" name="bananaQty" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Cherries</td><td> <input type="text" id="cherryQty" name="cherryQty" > </td></tr>
...
```

Comment: This plugin was not designed for this type of non-binary behavior.  Either valid or invalid... no such thing as "warning".   The first posted answer below is probably the closest you're going to get.

Comment: @Sparky: It's no fun to use tools only the way they were designed! See accepted answer below for the solution.

Comment: I'm glad you finally figured out a workaround.  Utilizing the custom callbacks for `highlight` and `unhighlight` as you've done is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, in hindsight, was simple. The difficult part was figuring out where to find the text of the current error message to determine whether it is an Error or a Warning and how, exactly, to correctly update the input and message classes.

The method used to update the input class was standard, using addClass and removeClass in the `highlight` option. However this does not work for the message class, because the first time it runs, the message element has not yet been created. Instead, we change the value of errorClass before the message element is created, so the message element is then created with the desired class.

Caveat: This works for me. It might not work for you. Only basic testing has been done. There might be bugs. Use at your own risk.

CSS

```
.error {
    color:red;
}

.warn {
    color:darkorange;
}
```

JavaScript

```
<!-- Define jquery validation methods for input fields -->
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#inputForm").validate(
          {
              rules:
              {
                  appleQty:{min:0, max:100, range: [4, 8]},
                  bananaQty:{min:0, max:100, range: [2, 4]},
                  cherryQty:{min:0, max:100, range: [80, 85]}
              },

              highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                  // Get message text for current error.
                  errorMessage = $("#inputForm").validate().errorList[0].message;
                  if (errorMessage.includes("Warning")) {
                      // Set input field class to "warn".
                      $(element).removeClass("error").addClass("warn");
                      // Set message class to "warn".
                      // Note: addClass/removeClass does not work here because the first time this runs
                      // the message element is not yet created.
                      this.settings.errorClass = "warn";
                  } else {
                      // Set input field class to "error"
                      $(element).removeClass("warn").addClass("error");
                      // Set message class to "error";
                      // Note: addClass/removeClass does not work here because the first time this runs
                      // the message element is not yet created.
                      this.settings.errorClass = "error";
                  }
              },
              unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                  $(element).removeClass("error");
                  $(element).removeClass("warn");
              }
          });
    });
    // Order is significant. Conditions are evaluated from
    // most severe to least severe, with warning last.
    jQuery.validator.messages.number = 'Error: Input must be a number.';
    jQuery.validator.messages.min = 'Error: Minimum value is {0}.';
    jQuery.validator.messages.max = 'Error: Maximum value is {0}.';
    jQuery.validator.messages.range = 'Warning: Expected range is {0} to {1}.';
</script>
```

HTML

```
...
<tr><td>Apples</td><td> <input type="text" id="appleQty" name="appleQty" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Bananas</td><td> <input type="text" id="bananaQty" name="bananaQty" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Cherries</td><td> <input type="text" id="cherryQty" name="cherryQty" > </td></tr>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

CSS

```
.error {
    color:red;
}
.warning{
    color:orange;
}
```

Javascript

```
jQuery.validator.messages.min = '<span class="error">Error: Minimum value is {0}.</span>';
jQuery.validator.messages.max = '<span class="error">Error: Maximum value is {0}.</span>';
jQuery.validator.messages.range = '<span class="warning">Warning: Expected range is {0} to {1}.</span>';
```

Comment: Upvoted because I appreciate the effort and it does work, mostly. (It changes the color of the message, but not the text in the input field.) Maybe I am being too OCD, but I am still hoping to find a solution that works in cooperation with jQuery instead of overriding it.

Comment: This is what happens under the hood: ```<label class="error" ...><input ... class="error" ...><span class="warning">Warning: ...</span></label>```. jQuery is setting ```class="error"``` for the input and message elements, then we are overriding the class of the message element with our own ```class="warning"```. What I would like to find, if possible, is a way to make jQuery use the warning class instead of the error class for both the input and the message.